# python:inspect.getmembers to locals() vs import

Tags: python

in django, instead of

```
from app.models import xxx,xxx,xxx
```

I can

```
from app import models as app_models
for name,value in inspect.getmembers(app_models, predicate=inspect.isclass):
    locals()[name] = value
```

Does this has any drawbacks? what's the difference between these two pattern?

Comment: You mean `globals()`, right? In a module the two are the same, I know, but still.

Comment: And why not add `__all__ = ['xxx', 'xxy', 'xxz']` to your `models.py`, then do `from app.models import *` instead?